# Soma de colunas

Tags: c

Preciso realizar a soma de cada coluna de uma matriz 3X3.
[image: Questão]

O que tenho até agora:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int matriz[3][3] = 
    {
        { 5, -8, 10 },
        { 1, 2, 15 },
        { 25, 10, 7}
    };
  
    int array[3] = {0};
    
    for(int linha = 0; linha < 3; linha++){
        for(int coluna = 0; coluna < 3; coluna++){
            printf("%d  ", matriz[linha][coluna]);    
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    int soma;
    for(int lin = 0; lin < 3; lin++){
        soma = 0;
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++){
            soma = soma + matriz[lin][col];   
        }
        array[col] = soma;
    }
    
    printf("\nA soma das colunas da matriz é:\n");
    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++){
        printf("%d  ", array[r]);   
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: E a dúvida qual é? Diga uma que seja pontual e específica.

Comment: Você falou o que quer fazer, mas não descreveu o problema que está tendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você inverteu os loops na soma. Para somar as colunas primeiro varie as colunas e internamente varie as linhas de cada coluna.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int matriz[3][3] = { { 5, -8, 10 }, { 1, 2, 15 }, { 25, 10, 7}  };
      
    int array[3] = {0};

    for(int linha = 0; linha < 3; linha++){
        for(int coluna = 0; coluna < 3; coluna++){
            printf("%d  ", matriz[linha][coluna]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    int soma;
    for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++){
        soma = 0;
        for(int lin = 0; lin < 3; lin++){
            soma = soma + matriz[lin][col];   
        }
        array[col] = soma;
    }

    printf("\nA soma das colunas da matriz é:\n");
    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++){
        printf("%d  ", array[r]);   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando em https://ideone.com/h8DZCj

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Você não especificou o problema que está encontrando, mas aqui vai uma solução em java que parece bem similar a C então dá pra pegar a ideia.

```
        int[][] matriz = new int[3][3];
        int[] novo = new int[3];
        for (int linha = 0; linha < matriz.length; linha++) {
                for (int coluna = 0; coluna < matriz.length; coluna++) {
                novo[coluna]+=matriz[linha][coluna];
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

tem dois problemas no seu segundo loop, que faz a soma das colunas.

1. Você precisa percorrer entre colunas e não entre linhas. Troque a ordem das referencias da matriz de `matriz[lin][col]` para `matriz[col][lin]`
2. tem um erro na linha onde você coloca a soma no seu array, você está usando a variavel `col` que não existe fora do loop dela, quando deveria ser a variavel `lin`. Substitua `array[col] = soma;` por `array[lin] = soma;`

Trecho com correções:

```c
    for(int lin = 0; lin < 3; lin++){
        soma = 0;
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++){
            soma = soma + matriz[col][lin];   
        }
        array[lin] = soma;
    }
```